# How to make text in a textblock display above (foreground) all elements in the same space

Tags: gojs

Below is the code sample. I'm just trying to get the textblock to render above the other elements involved. There are numerous elements being rendered, but the primary problem is:
The horizontal and vertical lines used to draw a visible grid are obscuring the text underneath.
I need to be able to either make the grid lines further back in z-position or move the text to foremost layer or z-pos.

```
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add('Slant',
                    $(go.Node, "Spot",`enter code here`

                        new go.Binding("location", "", function (data) {
                            // Different data items have x/y this in different formats...
                            var x = data.XPos || 0;
                            var y = data.slantShelfVirtualYpos * -1 || 0;
                            return new go.Point(x, y);
                        }),
                        // shelf
                        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
                            { strokeWidth: 1 },
                            { fill: $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0.0: "white", 1.0: "gray" }) },
                            new go.Binding('width', '', function (x) { return x.ShelfLength }),
                            new go.Binding('height', '', function (x) {

                                return x.slantShelfHeightOffset ;
                            }),
                        ),
                        // guardrail vertical lines
                        $(go.Panel, "Grid",
                            {
                                gridCellSize: new go.Size(10, 10),
                                alignment: go.Spot.Bottom,
                                alignmentFocus: go.Spot.Bottom
                            },
                            $(go.Shape, "LineV", { strokeWidth: 1 }),
                            new go.Binding('width', '', function (x) { return x.ShelfLength  }),
                            new go.Binding('height', '', function (x) { return x.GuardRailHeight }),
                        ), // end of guardrail Vertical lines
                        // guardrail top horizontal rail
                        $(go.Panel, "Grid",
                            {
                                gridCellSize: new go.Size(10, 10),
                                alignment: go.Spot.Bottom,
                                alignmentFocus: go.Spot.Bottom
                            },
                            $(go.Shape, "LineH", { strokeWidth: 1 }),
                            new go.Binding('width', '', function (x) { return x.ShelfLength }),
                            new go.Binding('height', '', function (x) { return x.GuardRailHeight }),
                        ), // end of guardrail Vertical lines
                        $(go.TextBlock, {

                            font: '7px sans-serif',
                            alignment: go.Spot.BottomLeft,
                            alignmentFocus: go.Spot.BottomLeft
                        },
                            new go.Binding("text", "", function (x) { 
                               return "shelf:" + x.ShelfNumber + " Ypos: " + x.YPOS + " type:" + 
                               x.ShelfTypeName + " Slope:" + x.Slope })
                        ),
                    ),// end of shelf number text box

                ); // end of the slant shelf template
```

Answer (score 0):

The **TextBlock** is indeed in front of the "Grid" **Panel**, due to the order within their containing **Panel**.

I suggest that you set the **TextBlock.background** to a light color:

```
  $(go.TextBlock,
    {
      background: "white",
      . . .
    })
```

Comment: This is exactly what was needed. Thanks so much.